# Correct understanding of imrect MATLAB operation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, crop, segment

I have an image,

[image: 3 FIGURES].

I wanted to do this:

[image: 3 FIGURES]

After doing some operation, I should be able to recombine the images to get the final result. My code is this:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
tic
I = imread('ChanVese.jpg');
I = imresize(I, [128 128]);
Img = I;
I = double(I(:, :, 1));

figure();
imshow(Img);
% // As there are three figures
crop_pos = zeros(3, 4);
new_image = zeros(size(I));
c = cell(1, 3);
for i=1:3
    % // Sub-divide the image
    h = imrect(gca);
    % // To make the rect function bounded within the image size
    addNewPositionCallback(h, @(p) title(mat2str(p, 3)));
    fcn = makeConstrainToRectFcn('imrect', get(gca, 'XLim'), get(gca, 'YLim'));
    setPositionConstraintFcn(h, fcn);
    crop_area = wait(h)
    crop_pos(i, :) = (crop_area);
    % // Cropped is the new cropped image on which we will do our operation
    cropped = (imcrop(Img, crop_area));
    c{i} = cropped;


    % // Do operation on the image
    %***************************
    % Code to be written
    %***************************


    % // Insert the part-image back into the image
    new_image(crop_pos(i, 2):crop_pos(i, 4), crop_pos(i,1):crop_pos(i, 3)) = c{i};
end

imagesc(new_image, [0 255]),colormap(gray);axis on
toc
```

My problem is with the imrect function: I will try to give an example. Even if I select the whole of the image whose size is [128x128],
I get an output of crop_pos as

```
[x,y,w,h] = [0.5, 0.5, 128, 128]
```

whereas, it actually should be

```
[x, y, w, h] = [1, 1, 128, 128];
```

Also sometimes the width and the height are given in floating point. Why is this so? I believe that MATLAB handles images as matrixes and doing so converts them into discrete components. So all values should be in integers.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

For me, in most cases, it is enough to write

```
crop_area = round(wait(h))
```

instead of

```
crop_area = wait(h)
```

As I noticed, `imrect` behaves strangely when:

- An image is zoomed in or out, so the physical screen pixels do not match image pixels one-to-one (zoom level ~= 100%)
- A rectangle has constraints with `makeConstrainToRectFcn` and then was moved/resized to the limits

But these are my personal observations. There might be even platform-related issues in this case, I do not know.

1<sup>st</sup> issue may be solved with `imshow(Image, 'InitialMagnification',100);` if the image is smaller then screen. Otherwise you'll need `imscrollpanel` and `imoverviewpanel`.

Comment: you are correct in your assessment. But can you tell me how we can do so , so that the physical screen pixels matches with the image pixels ?

Comment: @roni, You have to force zoom level to be exact 100%, see my edit to the answer

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the difference is that the rect description used by imrect, imcrop, etc. does not refer to the pixel centers, but to the pixel boundaries. As stated in the documentation for imcrop:

> Because rect is specified in terms of spatial coordinates, the width and
> height elements of rect do not always correspond exactly with the size
> of the output image. For example, suppose rect is [20 20 40 30], using
> the default spatial coordinate system. The upper-left corner of the
> specified rectangle is the center of the pixel (20,20) and the
> lower-right corner is the center of the pixel (50,60). The resulting
> output image is 31-by-41, not 30-by-40, because the output image
> includes all pixels in the input image that are completely or
> partially enclosed

A solution for you would be to convert the rect vector to row and column indices with, for example, a function such as:

```
function [x,y] = rect2ind(rect)
%RECT2IND convert rect vector to matrix index vectors
% [x,y] = rect2ind(rect) converts a rect = [left top width height] vector
% to index vectors x and y (column and row indices, respectively), taking
% into account that rect specifies the location and size with respect to
% the edge of pixels. 
%
% See also IMRECT, IMCROP

left = rect(1);
top = rect(2);
width = rect(3);
height = rect(4);

x = round(left + 0.5):round(left + width - 0.5);
y = round(top + 0.5):round(top + height - 0.5);
```